# Convertir datos R

Tags: base-de-datos, r, dataframe, datos

Tengo una base de datos en *Excel* con columnas que tienen montos con formato moneda `$123,356.00` (por ejemplo) y al exportarla en R esos datos me los reconoce de tipo *character*.

¿Cómo le hago para convertirla en datos de tipo numérico y quitar el signo de pesos **`$`**? muchas gracias

Atendiendo las respuestas que ya me han dado, la manera en la que llamo la base de *Excel* es de esta forma:

```
datos <- read_excel("base.xlsx")
```

Pero los datos salen en *character* y no *numeric*, haciendo lo que otro compañero me sugirió, hice lo siguiente:

```
datos$col <- gsub("\\$", " ", datos$col)
```

Lo cual si me quito los "$" pero al convertirlo en numeric con el siguiente código:

```
datos$col <- as.numeric(datos$col)
```

Me apareció el siguiente error:

> Warning message:
> NAs introduced by coercion

Y todos los valores en la columna me los volvió NA =(

Les agradezco mucho de antemano.

Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenida Diana Camarillo a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Como definición general, si en el excel la columna es numérica (independientemente del formato en que se muestra) deberías poder importarla sin problemas, siempre que uses los parámetros y funciones adecuadas. Para poder darte una respuesta más precisa, deberíamos ver como estás importando la planilla (agrega el código en R editando tu pregunta) y eventualmente un ejemplo del archivo a importar.

Comment: Podrías quitar el símbolo con datos$col <- gsub("\\$", " ", datos$col)  y luego pasarlo a numérico con  datos$col <- as.numeric(datos$col ). Pero como bien dice Patricio Moracho estaría bien saber como has importado los datos.